# wp_editor not adding paragraphs despite wpautop being set to true

Tags: wp-editor, wp-autop

I'm using the following code to produce a `wp_editor` instance:

```
<?php if (version_compare($wp_version, "3.3") >= 0) { ?>
    <p><?php wp_editor(  $answer->post_content, 'answer', array( 'media_buttons' => true, 'wpautop' => true ) ); ?></p>
<?php } else { ?>
    <p><textarea name="answer" class="wp32"><?php echo esc_textarea( $answer->post_content ); ?></textarea></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Yet for some reason, [the **answer** content](http://www.seriouslyfish.com/questions/how-do-i-go-to-the-next-page/) isn't displaying with paragraphs.

The HTML for the **question** content is:

```
<div id="question-content"><p>I am somehow missing it.&nbsp;&nbsp; When I go to the “Knowledge Base” and click on “Tetras”</p>
<p>I get one page of tetra descriptions starting with the “A”s.</p>
<p>How do I get to the next page????</p>
</div>
```

But the HTML content for the **answer** is:

```
<div class="answer-content">
                Hi Jim,

The Tetras that you're seeing there are currently the only Tetras marked as being in that group!

Matt is working fervently to update the species database to our new website format, so at the moment, not every species is marked as being in the correct Knowledge Base groups.

Please bear with us!            </div>
```

---

**EDIT: Printing out the answer content**

```
    foreach ( $answers->posts as $answer ) {
        setup_postdata( $answer );
?>
    <div id="answer-<?php echo $answer->ID; ?>" class="answer">
        <?php the_answer_voting( $answer->ID ); ?>
        <div class="answer-body">
            <div class="answer-content">
                <?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="answer-meta">
                <?php the_qa_action_links( $answer->ID ); ?>
                <?php the_qa_author_box( $answer->ID ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
```

---

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You may have issues with your DOCTYPTE declaration also. I couldn't tell if the issues were caused by improperly displaying your content or if it's because the DOCTYPE declaration. You have improper html characters/entities that are either a product of the above issues, or may be in you Database code. A lot of "I'm not sure", but maybe it helps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `the_content()` not `echo get_the_content();`.

As you can see in `wp-includes/default-filters.php` `wpautop` is added for the filter `'the_content'` which is called in `the_content()`.

Comment: Tadaaaa! Thanks mate. I did wonder why `the_content()` hadn't been used. Implemented your solution and it works correctly.

Comment: You could also use `echo apply_filter( 'the_content', get_the_content() );`. Not that it makes much sense, but you _could_ mimic the core function :)

Comment: @kaiser you'd have to use apply_filters() now. Not sure if this was changed in a later version or not.